# JSON combined with python loop to only print integers

Tags: python, loops, count, increment

I'm trying to loop through integers that are in the json list based on a variable provided before. Here is my JSON list:

```
    tracks =[
   {
      'album_name':'Nevermind',
      1:'Smells like teen spirit',
      2:'In Bloom',
      3:'Come as you are',
      4:'Breed',
      5:'Lithium',
      6:'Polly',
      7:'Territorial Pissings',
      8:'Drain You',
      9:'Lounge act',
      10:'Stay away',
      11:'On a plain',
      12:'Something in the way'
   },
   {
      'album_name':'Relapse',
      1:'Hello',
      2':'3AM',

   },

]
```

And this is my html loop:

```
<div class="single_album">
    <h2>Track list</h2>
    {% for tracks in tracks if tracks.album_name == album_name %}
        <ol>
            <li>{{ tracks[x] }}</li>
        </ol>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

If I put 1 instead of 'x' it works, as it prints record number one which is "1:'Smells like teen spirit'" However I don't know how to make a loop in which the x will increment each time it loops as I Im not sure whether it should be placed in python or html file.

Comment: tracks is a list or array(js) of dicts or objects(js) you can access them `tracks[0].album_name`

Comment: Im getting an error from python "UndefinedError: dict object has no element 0"

Comment: You're also using "tracks" to refer both to your list of dictionaries, and to the particular album you're dealing with in the loop. You want (something like) "for track in tracks", and then use 'track' to refer to the album.

Comment: aha `{{ tracks[1] }}` working because of 1 is the key

Comment: Yes but I can't name all my record "track" in the list "tracks" as it will only return one item, therefore I need to loop it through and thats what Im struggling with.

Comment: inside loop you can use this `{% for key, value in track.items %} 
  <li>{{value}}</li>
 {% endfor %}`

Comment: It doesn't work, it says "track is undefined". Tried changing it to "tracks" and this came up "TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable".

Comment: try this full code `<div class="single_album">
    <h2>Track list</h2>
    {% for track in tracks if tracks.album_name == album_name %}
        <ol>
            {% for key, value in track.items %} <li>{{value}}</li> {% endfor%}
        </ol>
    {% endfor %}
</div>`

Comment: Its blank, I tried to change the records in JSON to "track" and still nothing shows up.

Comment: remove if condition in first loop and try

Comment: This error shows up "TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable". And with the if statement its blank.

Comment: If the 'if' makes it blank, probably worth adding  {{ album_name }} temporarily to your template just to check that the value is being passed correctly.

Comment: check answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
In [15]: from django.template import Template,Context    
In [16]: tracks =[
        ...:    {
        ...:       'album_name':'Nevermind',
        ...:       1:'Smells like teen spirit',
        ...:       2:'In Bloom',
        ...:       3:'Come as you are',
        ...:       4:'Breed',
        ...:       5:'Lithium',
        ...:       6:'Polly',
        ...:       7:'Territorial Pissings',
        ...:       8:'Drain You',
        ...:       9:'Lounge act',
        ...:       10:'Stay away',
        ...:       11:'On a plain',
        ...:       12:'Something in the way'
        ...:    },
        ...:    {
        ...:       'album_name':'Relapse',
        ...:       1:'Hello',
        ...:       2:'3AM',
        ...:
        ...:    },
        ...:
        ...: ]

    In [17]: t = Template("""<div class="single_album"> <h2>Track list</h2> {% for track in tracks %} {%if track.album_name == album_name %}<ol> {% for key, value in track
        ...: .items %} {%if key != 'album_name' %}<li>{{value}}</li>{%endif%} {% endfor%} </ol>{%endif%} {% endfor %} </div>""")

    In [18]: c = Context({"tracks": tracks,'album_name':'Nevermind'})

    In [19]: t.render(c)
    Out[19]: u'<div class="single_album"> <h2>Track list</h2>  <ol>  <li>Smells like teen spirit</li>  <li>In Bloom</li>  <li>Come as you are</li>  <li>Breed</li>  <li>Lithium</li>  <li>Polly</li>  <li>Territorial Pissings</li>  <li>Drain You</li>  <li>Lounge act</li>  <li>Stay away</li>  <li>On a plain</li>  <li>Something in the way</li>    </ol>    </div>'

    In [20]:
```

Comment: Nice lightweight way to demonstrate it! Do you have any advice on how to set up just enough of the Dango settings to shut up the 'ImproperlyConfigured' exceptions?

Comment: simple create empty project the in command line or terminal type: `python manage.py shell `then python REPL opens and no 'ImproperlyConfigured' exceptions

Comment: you can create empty project using `django-admin startproject <project_name>`

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this is the error I get "NameError: global name 'template' is not defined". I have no idea hows that even possible..

Comment: "NameError: global name 'template' is not defined" - thats the error. If I remove the whole t = template stuff then it shows an error for context = "NameError: global name 'context' is not defined"

Comment: replace old template with new this `<div class="single_album"> <h2>Track list</h2> {% for track in tracks %} {%if track.album_name == album_name %}<ol> {% for key, value in track
    ...: .items %} {%if key != 'album_name' %}<li>{{value}}</li>{%endif%} {% endfor%} </ol>{%endif%} {% endfor %} </div>`  then it should work fine

Comment: I think the import statement has got lost from the example:

`from django.template import Template,Context`

Comment: Yes may be but should have a template and a view just update old template